# Is there a reference translation of the Declaration of Human Rights?

Tags: contemporary-latin

I know of two translations of the Declaration of Human Rights:

- https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Universalis_de_jure_hominum_declaratio
- https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Universa_humanorum_iurium_declaratio

But both are anonymous and without source.
Is there a reference translation of this text? Or at least a translation whose author and/or quality of language is recognised?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and very interesting question! I really hope someone knows or can find out...

Comment: @Rafael Unless I'm mistaken, it's a welcome back...

Answer (score 4):

Both of the translations that you linked to are in the [library of UDHR translations](https://searchlibrary.ohchr.org/search?ln=en&cc=UDHR+Translation+Collection&p=&f=&action_search=Search) on the [official site of the United Nations Office of the High Commissioner for Human Rights](https://www.ohchr.org/). The site doesn't 'privilege' either translation in any way.

The first translation was done by students (apparently) of the [Liceo Ginnasio Statale "Socrate" in Rome](https://www.ohchr.org/en/human-rights/universal-declaration/translations/latin-latina-0?LangID=ltn1).

The second was done by students at the [Gymnase de Nyon in Switzerland](https://www.ohchr.org/en/human-rights/universal-declaration/translations/latin-latina?LangID=ltn).

I believe that, at one time, the translations posted on the OHCHR site weren't attributed in any way. This may explain why the Wikisource pages don't give any sort of author information.